# MediaWiki - Searching based on PageID

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I'm using MediaWiki at work and creating a Knowledge Base. We've got everything set up but one requirement is to have a unique identifier on each page, then it can be referenced in official documentation. I've done this by using the magic word `{{PAGEID}}` so it's added to the bottom right of each page.

Another requirement is to be able to find the page based on this unique number but when using the built in search function the page can't be found.

For example, the main page has the text "Page ID:1" in the bottom right corner. When doing a search for "Page ID:1" nothing can be found and the Wiki only gives me the option to create the page.

Does anyone know how you can either search on, or have the search include the Page ID?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: While this does not really answer your question, note that you can link directly to a page using its ID with a URL like this: https://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?curid=9016

Comment: I know about that method, but the terms I'm following are quite strict and don't accept that as a solution unfortunately. Upper management want a way to search using the unique number instead so it shows the target pages in the search results. I'm hoping that's possible.

Comment: The problem with searching for `Page ID:1` that it's searching the wikitext. If you search for `Page ID:{{PAGEID}}` it'll work. :-(

Comment: I tried searching like you said Sam Wilson but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
global $wgHooks;
$wgHooks['SearchGetNearMatchBefore'][] = function ( array $allSearchTerms, &$titleResult ) {
    $searchTerm = $allSearchTerms[0];
    if ( preg_match( '/^id:\d+$/', $searchTerm ) ) {
        $pageId = (int)substr( $searchTerm, 3 );
        $titleResult = Title::newFromID( $pageId );
        return false;
    }
};
```

will jump to the page with ID `123` when you enter `id:123` in the search box. Seems like a silly way to use search though.

Comment: This initially doesn't work but it gives me a good place to start thank you.
It does give error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$wgFileExtensions' (T_VARIABLE) in D:\www\wiki\LocalSettings.php` though so I'll need to see if it's something that's possible to fix.

Comment: Sounds like an error in your settings that's unrelated to this snippet (which does not use that variable).

Comment: Shouldn't there be a semicolon at the end? That might account for the error reported by @Groveham, if they're setting `$wgFileExtensions` on the next line in their LocalSettings.php.